# HttpSession changes after closing the browser

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, session

I am creating a spring boot application in my free time and currently I am working on using session to keep track of the logged in user.
The problem I have is that every time I close the browser and open it again my session expires (the ID changes) and I have to log in again.

**Here's my simple code for using the session:**

```
@GetMapping("/explore")
public String explore(HttpSession session){
    //This prints different results after closing the browser
    System.out.println(session.getId());
    if(session.getAttribute("user") != null) {
        thisUser = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
    }
    return "explore";
}
```

**And I add the user object to the session like this (validation omitted for simplicity):**

```
@PostMapping("/login")
public String logging(User user, HttpSession session){
        session.setAttribute("user", user);
        return "redirect:/explore";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's conform the specified behaviour. The session cookie doesn't have an age, so it lives as long as the client has the webbrowser instance open or until the client hasn't visited the website for long as specified in the session-timeout setting in the server side.

You basically want a cookie which lives longer than the session cookie. You can create a new long-living cookie using Cookie API, set its age using Cookie#setMaxAge(), add it to the HTTP response using HttpServletResponse#addCookie(). On the subsequent HTTP requests you can determine the presence of the cookie using HttpServletRequest#getCookies().

Answer (score 0):

Use Cookie.
Cookie is a small piece of data stored on the client-side which servers use when communicating with clients.

```
Cookie authCookie = new Cookie("AUTH", user.getUserName());
authCookie.setMaxAge(60*60);
response.addCookie(authCookie);
```